# Where can I ask about jMonkey

Tags: jmonkeyengine

I am creating a game with and new to jMonkey engine. Questions were raised about the jme3 during developments. But I cannot find any place to post and get answered.

these are the links I tried. http://jmonkeyengine.org/ , http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/, http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:faq

But I could not find a place to post it. I sent a message to contact@monkeyengine.org, but I did not receive a reply. Can someone please tell me where to post the questions on jMonkey.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [the official jme3 forum](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/?PHPSESSID=dd3f423c8203c6d56eaafcaccb13676d;www) where the latest postings and a form to post your [question is at the bottom of the page if you log in](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/latest-posts/).

[image]

Comment: At the bottom I can only see " Viewing 16 topics - 1 through 15 (of 30,374 total) ". Can you please give me an exact place's link to post question.

Comment: Please use [this link](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/board/troubleshooting/general-2/) and the form for posting your question is at the bottom.